# Oracle: How to create an element in a specific namespace with XMLElement()

Tags: xml, oracle

In Oracle, you can use the [XMLElement()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions230.htm#i1129193) function to create an element, as in:

```
XMLElement('name', 'John')
```

But how to create an element in a specific namespace? For instance, how to create the following element:

```
<my:name xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my">John</my:name>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `XMLElement()` use:

```
XMLType('<my:name xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my">John</my:name>')
```

Yes, it is that simple.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use XMLAttribute:

```
select xmlelement("my:name",
        xmlattributes('http://www.example.com/my' as "xmlns:my"),
        'John'
       )
from dual
```

Will return:

```
<my:name xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my">John</my:name>
```

You can also check that Oracle recognizes this as a namespace (other than you are not getting a *namespace prefix "my" is not declared* error):

```
select xmlelement("my:name",
        xmlattributes('http://www.example.com/my' as "xmlns:my"),
        'John'
       ).getnamespace()
from dual
```

Will return:

```
http://www.example.com/my
```

Comment: Ah, interesting. You can really use an xmlattributes() to define a namespace? Feels like a stretch to me, but if this works, this is a good one!

Comment: > (other than you are not getting a namespace prefix "my" is not declared error): What if you are getting that error ?