# Using XSLT to create a PLSQL statement to output XML

Tags: xml, xslt, plsql

I have searched the internet for a tool to do this but I have not found one so I thought it should be simple to create myself.
I want to create a XSLT where I input an arbitrary xml file and it will output a select statement that I can use inside an Oracle database to generate the input xml.

E.g.
If I give it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test xmlns="dddd" xmlns:xxx="ddd222" someatt="val">
    <xxx:f>E</xxx:f>
    <g>G</g>
    <h xmlns="anotherns">H</h>
    <zz:i xmlns:zz="yetanotherns">I</zz:i>
</test>
```

I want the following output:

```
select 
    xmlelement("test"
    ,xmlattributes(
      'dddd' as "xmlns"
      ,'ddd222' as "xmlns:xxx"
      ,'val' as "someatt"
    )
        ,xmlelement("xxx:f",'E')
        ,xmlelement("g",'G')
        ,xmlelement("h"
      ,xmlattributes('anotherns' as "xmlns")
      ,'H'
    )
        ,xmlelement("zz:i"
      ,xmlattributes('yetanotherns' as "xmlns:zz")
      ,'I'
    )
  )
from dual;
```

I am almost all the way there. I can make the following output with my current XSLT:

```
select 
    xmlelement("test"
        ,xmlattributes(
            'val' as "someatt"
        )
        ,xmlelement("xxx:f",'E')
        ,xmlelement("g",'G')
        ,xmlelement("h",'H')
        ,xmlelement("zz:i",'I')
        )
from dual;
```

Which is perfect except it is missing the xmlns attributes. The problem is the xmlns and xmlns:*** attributes in the input document are not being treated as normal attributes and don't seem to be visible when the xslt is run. 
Is there an optionto make them remain?

The xslt I have is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"

>
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">


    <xsl:text>select 
    </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>
from dual;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:text>xmlelement("</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select='name()'/>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>

    <!--Lots of tabs for indenting-->
<xsl:variable name='tabs' xml:space="preserve">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name='nl'><xsl:text>
    </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select='substring($tabs,0,count(ancestor::*)+2)'/></xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name='att_children' select='count(@*)'/>
    <xsl:if test="$att_children &gt; 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
        <xsl:text>,xmlattributes(</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select='./@*'>
            <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/><xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>' as "</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
        <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>


    <xsl:variable name='children' select='count(*)'/>
    <!--<xsl:value-of select='$children'/>-->
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test='$children=0'>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select='text()'/>
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:for-each select='./*'>
                <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates select='.'/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test='$children &gt; 1'>
        <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()|@*"> </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `xmlns` is not an attribute, it is a namespace declaration. You can still access them in XSLT, but you probably need to read up on how XML namespaces are handled in PLSQL / Oracle so you know what output to generate first because it could probably be different to the expected output you are currently showing.

Comment: @TimC it seems that (weirdly) it is the same function to define attributes or namespaces, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437670/oracle-how-to-create-an-element-in-a-specific-namespace-with-xmlelement

Comment: Hi, yes I know what output I want from xslt, it is in the question. PLSQL treats xmlns as normal attributes and I have tested the statement in the question and it works.

Comment: My problem is how do I detect the xmlns namespace declarations in the input to xslt?

Answer (score 1):

I only have a part of the solution to your problem.

It consists of firstly, counting the namespaces to be output, in addition to the attributes:

```
<xsl:variable name='att_children' select='count(@* | namespace::*[not(name() = "xml")])'/>
```

Then also loop on the namespaces defined on your node (there is a extra predicate to avoid the default *xml* namespace):

```
<xsl:if test="$att_children &gt; 0">
    <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
    <xsl:text>,xmlattributes(</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select='./@* | namespace::*[not(name() = "xml")]'>
        <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/><xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>' as "</xsl:text>
        <xsl:choose>
          <!-- for real attributes -->
          <xsl:when test="self::attribute">
              <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <!-- for namespaces -->
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test='name() = ""'>xmlns</xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>xmlns:</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
    <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

This is what I obtain so far:

```
select 
    xmlelement("test"
     ,xmlattributes(
       'dddd' as "xmlns"
       ,'ddd222' as "xmlns:xxx"
       ,'val' as "xmlns:someatt"
     )
     ,xmlelement("xxx:f"
      ,xmlattributes(
        'dddd' as "xmlns"
        ,'ddd222' as "xmlns:xxx"
      ),'E')
     ,xmlelement("g"
      ,xmlattributes(
        'dddd' as "xmlns"
        ,'ddd222' as "xmlns:xxx"
      ),'G')
     ,xmlelement("h"
      ,xmlattributes(
        'anotherns' as "xmlns"
        ,'ddd222' as "xmlns:xxx"
      ),'H')
     ,xmlelement("zz:i"
      ,xmlattributes(
        'dddd' as "xmlns"
        ,'ddd222' as "xmlns:xxx"
        ,'yetanotherns' as "xmlns:zz"
      ),'I')
     )
from dual;
```

The limitation is that inherited namespaces are repeated over on every element. It is somewhat redundant but normally doesn't affect the effective XML.

I unfortunately wasn't able to find a way to check if the namespace has already been defined on an ancestor element, to avoid this repetition.

Comment: Yes, thanks for looking at this. Recalculating the namespaces is one option, but it gets very complicated. I would want to use the same name space prefixes as the input document but there is a possibility that the same prefix is used at different levels of the tree. There is also a possibility that the same namespace used different prefixes. I considered collecting all the namespaces in the document together and outputting them at the top level but it could break things. Following the rule of copying the declarations exactly as they are in the input document should be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can get exactly what you are after. The `namespace::` axis will return all namespaces in effect for a node, not necessarily when that namespace was declared (which might have been an ancestor node)

What you could do, is use the following expression, to try and check the first time a namespace prefix and uri appears in the XML

```
 <xsl:for-each select="namespace::*[name() != 'xml']">
      <xsl:if test="not(../ancestor::*/namespace::*[. = current()/. and name() = current()/name()])">
```

Try this XSLT (It might need some work on the formatting of the output)

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"

>
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">


    <xsl:text>select 
    </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>
from dual;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:text>xmlelement("</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select='name()'/>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>

    <!--Lots of tabs for indenting-->
<xsl:variable name='tabs' xml:space="preserve">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name='nl'><xsl:text>
    </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select='substring($tabs,0,count(ancestor::*)+2)'/></xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="namespaces">
        <xsl:if test="self::*">
                <xsl:for-each select="namespace::*[name() != 'xml']">
                    <xsl:if test="not(../ancestor::*/namespace::*[. = current()/. and name() = current()/name()])">
                        <xsl:text>,'</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                        <xsl:text>' as "xmlns</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:if test="name() != ''">
                            <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name='att_children' select='count(@*)'/>
    <xsl:if test="$att_children &gt; 0 or $namespaces != ''">
        <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
        <xsl:text>,xmlattributes(</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($namespaces, 2)" />
        <xsl:for-each select='./@*'>
            <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/><xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1 or $namespaces != ''"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>' as "</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
        <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>


    <xsl:variable name='children' select='count(*)'/>
    <!--<xsl:value-of select='$children'/>-->
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test='$children=0'>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select='text()'/>
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:for-each select='./*'>
                <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates select='.'/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test='$children &gt; 1'>
        <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()|@*"> </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This might not work in the case where you redefine a namespace prefix to a different URI, but then redefine it back to the original URI.